# WCF : Configuring message security programmatically

Tags: wcf, azure, configure

I'm coding an Azure WCF Service Bus service, which is to be configured programmatically to have message security using certificates:

```
        ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Tcp;

        // create the service URI based on the service namespace
        Uri address = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceNamespace"], "TestService");

        // create the credentials object for the endpoint
        TransportClientEndpointBehavior sharedSecretServiceBusCredential = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior();
        sharedSecretServiceBusCredential.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["issuerName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["issuerSecret"]);

        //Create and bind the serviceEndpoint
        ContractDescription contractDescription = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(ITestContract), typeof(TestServiceImpl));
        ServiceEndpoint serviceEndPoint = new ServiceEndpoint(contractDescription);
        serviceEndPoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(address);    

        var NetTcpRelayBinding = new NetTcpRelayBinding(EndToEndSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential, RelayClientAuthenticationType.RelayAccessToken);            
        NetTcpRelayBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate; //The serivice will check the TrustedPeople store for the client
        serviceEndPoint.Binding = NetTcpRelayBinding;
        serviceEndPoint.Behaviors.Add(sharedSecretServiceBusCredential);  

        Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestServiceImpl), address);

        //Add a service certificate            
        Host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerTrust;
        Host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine,StoreName.My,X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,"E86870F0118CE39D771A49B9337C28444F3C7348");            

        // create the service host reading the configuration
        Host.Description.Endpoints.Add(serviceEndPoint);
```

I can get this service up and running, however, any client )with just the ServiceBus SharedSecret, clientCredentials NOT set to use any cert) is able to call my service without any errors.
Is the above code sufficient to indicate that certificates (and only certificates base authorization) should be used for message security ?
Any good articles on configuring WCF message security programmatically ?

Comment: Supplementary to this, here's a link on how to programatically wire up to Windows Service Azure Bus with SimpleWebToken [http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/18/declaritively-and-programitcally-subscribing-to-the-windows-azure-service-bus-relay-with-wcf/](http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/18/declaritively-and-programitcally-subscribing-to-the-windows-azure-service-bus-relay-with-wcf/).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that lack of sleep was the culprit; I was running an older version of the service. Clients without any certificates do error out (with System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException was unhandled  Message=Error while reading message framing format at position 1 of stream (state: Start).

A properly coded up client for this is  :

```
        ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Tcp;

        string serviceNamespace = "valid-namespace";
        string issuerName = "owner";
        string issuerSecret = "validSecret";

        // create the service URI based on the service namespace
        Uri serviceUri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", serviceNamespace, "valid-namespace");

        // create the credentials object for the endpoint
        TransportClientEndpointBehavior sharedSecretServiceBusCredential = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior();
        sharedSecretServiceBusCredential.CredentialType = TransportClientCredentialType.SharedSecret;
        sharedSecretServiceBusCredential.Credentials.SharedSecret.IssuerName = issuerName;
        sharedSecretServiceBusCredential.Credentials.SharedSecret.IssuerSecret = issuerSecret;


        ChannelFactory<ITestChannel> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ITestChannel>();
        channelFactory.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(serviceUri);
        var NTRB = new NetTcpRelayBinding();
        NTRB.Security.Mode = EndToEndSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        NTRB.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
        channelFactory.Endpoint.Binding = NTRB;
        channelFactory.Endpoint.Contract.ContractType = typeof(ITestChannel);
        // apply the Service Bus credentials
        channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(sharedSecretServiceBusCredential);

        //Question : Why doesn't use of the following line effect Service-Validation ? I can successfully call the service from a machine where the server's certificate does NOT exist in the trusted-people store          
        //channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerTrust;

        channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "valid-thubmprint");
        // create and open the client channel          
        ITestChannel channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

        Console.WriteLine(channel.ServiceMethod());
        Console.ReadKey();
        channel.Close();
        channelFactory.Close();
```

Still have the problem of the ServiceCertificate always being assumed valid, even when PeerTrust is used for channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode and the service certificate isn't in the TrustedPeople store.
Anyone with ideas on why this happens ?